# git fatal error refs not found

Tags: git, fatal-error, git-bash, gitstack

I get this error when attempting to push to a windows server I have set up that is running GitStack.

`fatal: http://xx.xx.x.xxx/mjtest.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

This error seems to be quite common amongst people who are new to Git, GitBash and GitStack so I have found some possible solutions but none seem to work for me.

This is what I do that leads to the error, first I create an empty repository in GitStack called mjtest, I then create a user and add them to the repository and give them read and write access, then I use GitBash to create a local repository and try to push it.

```
git config --global user.name "XXXXXXX"
git config --global user.email XXXXXXX
mkdir ~/mjtest
cd ~/mjtest
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin http://XX.XX.X.XXX/mjtest.git
git push origin master
```

This then asks me for a username and then a password which I enter correctly. Once they are entered it returns the fatal error message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: I have, just by entering `git update-server-info`, and it doesn't seem to have any effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be related to a [control access issue](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitweb.html#_controlling_access_to_git_repositories).
This usually happen when the repo hasn't been set to be exported (by `git-daemon` or `gitweb`): GitStack could rely on a similar mechanism.
See [this thread](http://gitstack.com/questions/git-clone-fails-with-inforefs-not-found-did-you-run-git-update-server-info-on-the-server/) for instance/

> I created an 'empty' file with the name "`git-daemon-export-ok`' inside one of my repositories.
>   I can now clone / push / pull to this repository without issues.

That file should be created directly under the `xxx.git` root directory of your bare repo on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I created the file in my local repository using, `touch git-daemon-export-ok`, and tried to push to the remote repository but I still get the same error. Is there a particular place in my local repository that it must be placed into?

Comment: @MikeyJ It should be created just under the `xxx.git` root directory of your bare repo on the server.

Comment: @MikeyJ Excellent! I have edited the answer to make the path of that file more explicit.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez-Ocampo then it would be a good base for a new question (with the OS used, and Git version, both on server and client)

Answer (score 1):

I looked into C:/GitStack/apache/logs/error.log and found that GitStack was looking for the repository in the wrong location although its settings said D:/Repositories (my custom location), GitStack looked for the repositories in its default location. So I simply went and saved the settings again from GitStack admin page. It solved the problem.